# Framer Motion with NEXTjs and Chakra.ui animatePresence exit animation sometimes wont animate correctly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion, chakra-ui, tsx

I use framer motion animatePresence to add a little page transitions between my nextjs pages. I found this weird bug where sometime the exit animation just instantly move (from x: 0 to x:200) without animating, but fade works properly and never instant. This also happens only with animatePresence mode="wait".

here's the gif:
[App demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns6sv.gif)

my _app.tsx code:

```
  <AppSettingProvider>
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
          <Flex flexDir="column" minH="100vh">
            <Header />
            <Box
              h="100vh"
              pos="relative"
              px={{ base: "20px", md: "20px", lg: "25px", xl: "150px" }}
            >
              <Flex flexDir="column" minH="calc(100vh - 80px)">
                <Flex justifyContent="start" minH="100vh" pos="relative">
                  <Sidebar2 />
                  <Stack
                    w="full"
                    mt={{ base: "80px", xl: "100px" }}
                    mr={{ xl: "30px" }}
                    ml={{ xl: "5px" }}
                  >
                    <AnimatePresence initial={false} mode="wait">
                      <Component key={pageKey} {...pageProps} />
                    </AnimatePresence>
                  </Stack>
                </Flex>
              </Flex>
              <Footer />
            </Box>
          </Flex>
        </ChakraProvider>
      </AppSettingProvider>
    </>
```

my PageTransition.tsx:

```
function PageTransition({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <>
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, x: 200 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0, x: 200 }}
        transition={{duration: 0.2}}
      >
        {children}
      </motion.div>
    </>
  );
}
```

my page1 & page2 tsx:

```
 <>
      <PageTransition>
        
        <Box
          as="section"
          id="dashboard-hero-section"
          pb={{ base: "4", md: "8" }}
        >
          <Stack
            direction={{ base: "column", sm: "row" }}
            justifyContent="space-between"
            alignItems="center"
          >
            <Heading>Page 2</Heading>
          </Stack>

          <Box
          bg="red"
          width="500px"
          height="500px"
          >
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </PageTransition>
    </>
```

ive tried these following things:

- use different animation instead of x or y, only x or y do this
- clean my pages and _app
- put animatePresence outside of _app

Im expecting smooth animation everytime exit animation is running, but instead found this weird behaviour of randomly not animated and animated.

Answer (score 1):

I think i solved this. I removed every framer motions's "layout" in the tree, and so far no more weird behaviour happening. Will update this again if that behaviour appears again.